# python module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP' and other signals

Tags: python-3.x, macos, gcc, clang

```
C02TPARXG8WN:fal$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov 10 2019, 01:00:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import signal
>>> signal.SIGHUP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP'
>>>
```

testing signal on macos. unable to figure out why keep gettting signal error

```
C02TPARXG8WN:~ fc$ trap -l
```

1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP  6) SIGABRT  7) SIGEMT   8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL 10) SIGBUS  11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM 16) SIGURG
17) SIGSTOP 18) SIGTSTP 19) SIGCONT 20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGIO   24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ 26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH
29) SIGINFO 30) SIGUSR1 31) SIGUSR2

from my system, "trap -l" shows a selection of signal

Comment: Try `dir(signal)` to see what's defined. My Mac does have SIGHUP, btw.

Comment: If you want to see the signals defined within Python, you need to run the command I suggested within Python.

Comment: I did try it. but none of signal is defined1) SIGHUP 2) SIGINT 3) SIGQUIT 4) SIGILL 5) SIGTRAP 6) SIGABRT 7) SIGEMT 8) SIGFPE 9) SIGKILL 10) SIGBUS 11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGSYS 13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM 16) SIGURG 17) SIGSTOP 18) SIGTSTP 19) SIGCONT 20) SIGCHLD 21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGIO 24) SIGXCPU 25) SIGXFSZ 26) SIGVTALRM 27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH 29) SIGINFO 30) SIGUSR1 31) SIGUSR2

Comment: Huh? It's the first one, surely?

Comment: dir(signal)
['SignalHandler', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'signal', 'time']

Comment: Ok, `dir(signal.signal)`

Comment: the same :>>> dir(signal.signal)
['SignalHandler', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'signal', 'time']

Comment: Oh, your environment looks broken.

Comment: yes, my system has problem. i dont know how to fix it. in my another Linux machine, dir(signal) shows all signal name

Comment: I don't know how you can reinstall Python on a Mac - maybe try on AskDifferent Stack Exchange site. Another option might be to use **homebrew** Python which you can install/uninstall/reinstall as often as you like.

Comment: the version 3.6.9 is new installed

Comment: @MarkSetchell .  can you post your macos python info:[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Which Python are you running? Apple version or homebrew version. If homebrew version just remove and reinstall with `brew uninstall python` then `brew install python`.

Comment: I did brew uninstall python. It removed my python3 version. the python 2.7.10 version originally from my system works.  after i did a brew install python. it installed a python 3.7.x. the version doesn't work again

Answer (score 3):

I used this code before the `SIGHUP` usage to make it work on Windows, probably works on OS X too but I don't have a way to test it:

```
import platform
if platform.system() != 'Linux':
    signal.SIGHUP = 1
```

After that, comes the SIGHUP usage and since `1` is the initial value on Linux, it'll work just like it was supposed to.

Since Python 3.7 signal.SIGHUP only works on Unix systems, so that doesn't include Windows...

I used `platform.system() != 'Linux` since my script is only run on Windows and Linux, but you can accommodate it to your needs.

Platform docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system

Signal docs: [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/signal.html#signal.SIGHUP)

signal.SIGHUP value on Linux

```
>>> import signal
>>> signal.SIGHUP
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/signal.html), I would guess that either your device does not define `SIGHUP` inside `signal.h`, or that your python interpreter has been built on a device that is not completely equal to yours. If you are sure that `SIGHUP` is defined, you best guess is reinstalling or even compiling python yourself.

Comment: sudo find / -name "signal.h" | xargs grep "SIGHUP" it shows :/usr/include/sys/signal.h:#define SIGHUP 1 /* hangup */