# AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP'

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I am trying to integrate mod_wsgi into my django project on Windows 10. While I was able to install mod_wsgi into my virtual environment, I am running into errors while trying the command `python manage.py runmodwsgi`.

```
(venv) PS D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS> python manage.py runmodwsgi
Successfully ran command.
Server URL         : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root        : C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/mod_wsgi-localhost-8000-admin
Server Conf        : C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/mod_wsgi-localhost-8000-admin/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Temp/mod_wsgi-localhost-8000-admin/error_log (warn)
Operating Mode     : daemon
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Startup Timeout    : 15 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.cp1252
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS\manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Tutorials\Python\Projects\ADSS\venv\lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py", line 162, in handle
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGHUP'
```

Google seems to suggest that `signal.SIGHUP`, `signal.SIGUSR1` and `signal.SIGWINCH` as being used by my mod_wsgi installation aren't supported on Windows. So I tried the following two methods in `.\venv\Lib\site-packages\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py`:

1. I tried using the if-condition `if platform.system() != 'Linux':` as suggested on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58787330/python-module-signal-has-no-attribute-sighup-and-other-signals),
2. I also tried commenting out the lines making use of these signals in this file.

In either case, I kept running across some or the other error, making me wonder if my installation of mod_wsgi is correct at all.

I have been following the instructions as written on [mod_wsgi's PyPi listing](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/). I am writing them here for reference:

1. Obtained a copy of Apache 2.4.54 Win64 from https://www.apachelounge.com/download/
2. Extracted this zip file and placed the Apache24 folder in my C: as `C:\Apache24`.
3. Set `Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"` and `Listen 8000` in `httpd.conf`. Verified that things work and the default homepage is loaded (http://localhost:8000).
4. Installed Visual Studio C++ build tools using Visual Studio Installer (the 'Desktop development with C++' category).[image]
5. Installed mod_wsgi into my virtual environment by running the command `pip install mod-wsgi` in my active virtual environment in an `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VC2022` window.
6. Added `'mod_wsgi.server',` to the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` in my `settings.py`.
7. Ran `python manage.py collectstatic`
8. Ran `mod_wsgi-express module-config` which output the following three lines, which I placed at the end of my `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/Python310/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "D:/Tutorials/Python/Projects/ADSS/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "D:/Tutorials/Python/Projects/ADSS/venv"
```

9. Ran `python manage.py runmodwsgi`, which is resulting in the error log I mentioned at the start of my post.

Please throw light on what I might be doing incorrectly.

I also have Visual Studio installed, which I am using for this project.

I changed from port 80 to port 8000 in `httpd.conf` because my IIS doesn't allow Apache to run on port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So I found a workaround which works.
Instead of relying on mod_wsgi's buil-in admin script which is triggered by the command `python manage.py runmodwsgi`, I followed Johnnyboycurtis's method as explained in [his video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frEjX1DNSpc).

Johnnyboycurtis's method of django application deployment on Apache in Windows environment worked right out of the box. However, apache wasn't serving static files, even though I followed the instructions as per the django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

So, to serve the static files, I installed WhiteNoise. Now, things seem to be working fine.

Comment: I recently upgraded from python 3.10 to 3.11 and django 4.1 to 4.2 I had to change `LoadFile`  and `LoadModule` to python 3.11 dll file and the freshly compiled .pyd file corresponding to cpython 311.
`LoadFile "C:/Program Files/Python311/python311.dll"` and
`LoadModule wsgi_module "D:/Tutorials/Python/Projects/ADSS/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"`